# Netbeans and nodejs using

Tags: node.js, netbeans

Hi I'm creating nodejs app in netbeans ide. Every time when I'm changing js file I need manually restart server. Do You know how to do deploy automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NetBeans 8.0 supports Grunt, you can use grunt-contrib-watch (see [here](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch)). This plugins executes Grunt task (let's call it taskX) on file save. Then use grunt-exec (see [here](https://github.com/jharding/grunt-exec)) to define the taskX (that will be called by grunt-contrib-watch). The taskX should be configured to invoke command to stop and start NodeJS.

Finally, in NetBeans right click on Gruntfile.js (should be in project root directory), select Load tasks and select the grunt-contrib-watch.